# wtf form that rejects any html/javascript/sql injection

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I am attempting to have users enter a space/comma separated list of tags.  To that end, I want to reject html, sql injection and javascript for xsscripting.  Can I do this entirely in the wtf form?

```
class NewEntry(Form):
    '''
        A form for new entries
    '''
    title = TextAreaField("Title", validators=[Required()])
    text = PageDownField("Text", validators=[Required()])
    tags = TextAreaField("Tags", validators=[Required(validators.Required('Please add some tags.'))])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit', id="new_entry_submit_button")
```

Comment: Why don't you just properly escape the input in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, please explain

Comment: Injection attacks only work when the user's input is concatenated with a SQL command (for SQL injection) or output verbatim in another webpage (for HTML & JavaScript injection).  If you use parameterized SQL methods (*which you always should*) and convert `<>&` in arbitrary input to HTML entities on output, injection won't work.